# ionic2 android geolocation timeout

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am trying to get the default ionic2 geolocation plugin to run on my android test device. Works in browser and iOS, but fails with a timeout on android.

`PositionError {code: 3, message: "Timeout expired"}`

Here's the code

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ maximumAge: 60000, timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true }).then((position) => {
console.log(position);
}, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

The manifest contains

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

Yet it fails. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Trick 17 - seems on Android you sometimes have to delete the deployed app, reboot the phone and reinstall to update the app. Worked after this very procedure.

Comment: This worked for me. Testing an app with geolocation has been a real pain due to this and other odd gotchas.

Comment: I will also add that geolocation stopped working again a short time later with no apparent changes to my app or the emulator.